# How to assign a property to an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I want to assign a property to an object, that is part of an array of objects. The value shall be the value of an existing property of the object. How is this done?

```
    const data = [ {id: 111, name: 'AAA'}, ...];

    const result= data.map(item => {
      item.copyOfId= item.id;
      return item;
    });
```

Comment: So you just need the index of the object in the array as the value of `copyOfId`?

Comment: For reference: an array of objects is referred to as a _collection_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for `map` there, you just need to loop through the array, not *map* the array. So all the usual [ways of looping through arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript) apply, such as `forEach`:

```
const data = [ {id: 111, name: 'AAA'}, ...];
data.forEach(item => {
  item.copyOfId = item.id;
});
```

or `for-of`:

```
const data = [ {id: 111, name: 'AAA'}, ...];
for (const item of data) {
  item.copyOfId = item.id;
}
```

---

As [Mörre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544779/m%c3%b6rre) points out in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47535825/how-to-assign-a-property-to-an-array-of-objects/47535848#comment82028607_47535848), in functional programming `map` is indeed what you would reach for, but usually you'd create *new* objects to populate the new array, instead of modifying (mutating) the objects:

```
const data = [ {id: 111, name: 'AAA'}, ...];
const result = data.map(item => {
  return {...item, copyOfId: item.id};
});
```

*(That example uses [spread properties](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread), which are only a Stage 3 proposal but are supported by up-to-date Chrome and Firefox. You could use `Object.assign` instead. Either way, it's a shallow copy if that's important.)*

Comment: To elaborate on the `map`, it would be fine - IF he produced a completely new array (functional programming style, no mutations, etc.). But producing a new array while still mutating the content items - that's a conflicting message. Either all new (use `map`), or mutate (use `forEach`). Note that sure, you can use either one, it's just that there are certain associations/assumptions associated with those methods, which come from other languages.

Comment: @cale_b: `for-of`, arrow functions, and `const` are, `forEach` isn't. I'd say the question doesn't relate to ES2015 ("ES6") *specifically*, so probably not.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry, the index was wrong and i now corrected in the question, thanks for the fast answer

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different and shorter version (using object destructuring) would look like so:

```
const data = [ {id: 111, name: 'AAA'}, ...];

const result = data.map(({ id, name }) => ({ id, name, copyOfId: id }));
```

And using spread syntax:

```
const result = data.map(item => ({ ...item, copyOfId: item.id }));
```

Previous solutions work just as well, but I thought you may be interested in some additional ES2015 features.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` and within each iteration, you can use the `spread` operator to create a duplicate **BUT** new object.

```js
const data = [{
  id: 111,
  name: 'AAA'
}];

const result = data.map((item) => {      
  return { ...item, copyOfId: item.id };
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why? Doesn't he want a new array of objects?

Comment: Even if OP wanted new array of objects your answer is still wrong because it will produce new array of ids.

Comment: Where am I mutating the array though? Is this not pure?

Comment: You mutate the items in the array. Which still are the same ones in the old array, because those are object references. _EDIT: Before the edit._

Comment: @CarlEdwards - For what it's worth, I enjoy participating in SO (including answering) because I'm always learning from people way smarter than me.  So don't be discouraged by these comments - they are an invaluable education (which I'm learning from!)

Comment: @cale_b It's all good. I feel the same way on learning from the best. I think in this case I just jumped the gun a bit when submitting.